# How to set up a personal server using java programming language and jsp

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, httpurlconnection

I was wondering if this is possible. I was thinking of creating a server client application using java and jsp, but don't want to use online hosting services. Its my first time using jsp and I have little knowledge of java. So any advice will be greatly appreciated

http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/monitor-tomcat.html?gclid=CNyHxK3Jpa8CFWOc4godL0DEXA

I've read about tomcat server application, but I wasn't sure what to do.

thanks,

lean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  However, if you don't know JSPs and you know very little Java, you've got a lot to learn before you will be productive.

I suggest that you start by doing the Oracle Java Tutorial and the Oracle JSP and Servlet Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is simply a web server/servlet container.  Which means that is it is capable of accepting and processing http requests.  However, you only need to go through the trouble of configuring Tomcat once, then your web server is up and running.

In general, most of your work on a website will be developing the application itself, which would then be deployed in your the `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` directory as a `.war` file.  Tomcat knows how to handle it from there.

As far as application development is concerned, I recommend looking into the Spring Framework.  It's unquestionably one of the industry standards, and with annotation configuration you'll be up and running quite quickly.

There are a ton of blog posts detailing how to use Spring annotations.  For getting of the ground, I recommend [this good, if somewhat dated, tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/).  It doesn't use annotations, but it walks you through setting up your first website using Spring, Tomcat, JSP, and a database.